# Excel data connection updating all data EXCEPT one specific column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Using Excel 2013.

So I have a workbook (let's called it book B) that pulls a table from another workbook (the source file, book A). No fancy connections or custom queries, I've used the Excel interface for everything, changing nothing but disabling the background refresh.

The problem arises when I update the original table in book A and go to refresh the connection in book B. All the updates I've put in are carried across *except* the data in a single column.

I've populated columns A to AA. Upon updating, the values in column O (formatted as dates and appear as they should) are not carried over. But this only applies to new values. Values that were already present in book B remain there, but values that are in book A but not book B are not carried over - and let me reiterate, this ONLY happens for column O.

I've tried deleting the connection and adding it again - to no avail. It should be said that both files are stored on a network-mapped drive.

What witchcraft have I been cursed with and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the shift in hair color I just underwent, I should be close to retirement by now. I was wrong in my initial assessment - whether the values were already present in book B or not turned out to be inconsequential in its entirety.

For some ungodly reason, if a date value is not formatted the way its cell says it should be formatted, the value seems to get ignored not only by table refreshes, but seemingly also attempts at writing the values in VBA (but that's a separate topic).

Example: If the cell is date-formatted to `"dd:mm:yy"` and you paste a value that has `"dd:mm:yyyy"`, the pasted format will not only stick (meaning the values will display in the pasted format, but if you check what format the cell is supposed to have, it displays what you initially set), but something else seems "wrong" as well - notably visible by how the date is left-aligned by default, whereas it *should* be right-aligned. I'm not sure why this happens, but it must be related to the source material (I'm pasting data from a program written in 1996, so I assume there's some charset malfunction in the background, despite my efforts to correct the date formats programmatically before doing the final insertion).

Anyway - in this case, the value is not carried over during a table refresh. Throwing a text-to-column call with no delimiter on the column in question prior to the refresh solves everything.